# Example of maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, examples-counterexamples

As it's known , an holomorphic($\neq constant$) function $f:G\subseteq\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  has maximum modulus on $\partial G$ .
I wuold an example of a function holomorphic on a disk centered in the origin that take its maximum modulus in  a complex number with non zero immaginary part.

Comment: $\sin$ or $\cos$ would do fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about the identity map on the disc?

Comment: A masterstroke. Almost as helpful as http://mathoverflow.net/a/62749/83468